# header not found even though `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is set correctly

Tags: compiling, pkg-config, cpp

I've installed a library to `~/.local`. The environment variables are set as shown below:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/saga//.local/lib
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/home/saga//.local/lib/pkgconfig
```

There's an re2.pc file in `/home/saga//.local/lib/pkgconfig` whose contents are:

```
prefix=/home/saga//.local
exec_prefix=/home/saga//.local
includedir=/home/saga//.local/include
libdir=/home/saga//.local/lib

Name: re2
Description: RE2 is a fast, safe, thread-friendly regular expression engine.
Version: 0.0.0
Cflags: -std=c++11 -pthread -I${includedir}
Libs: -pthread -L${libdir} -lre2
```

There's an `re2` directory in `/home/saga//.local/include` which contains `re2.h`. But when I try to compile a program which includes re2.h, I get the following error:

```
$ g++ tst.cpp
tst.cpp:1:9: fatal error: re2/re2.h: No such file or directory
 #include<re2/re2.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

and

```
$ g++ tst2.cpp
tst.cpp:1:9: fatal error: re2.h: No such file or directory
 #include<re2.h>
         ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The output of `pkg-config --libs re2` is `-L/home/saga//.local/lib -pthread -lre2`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try querying pkgconfig so you can find out where the header is located?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abramshow do I do that?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The output of  `pkg-config --libs re2` is `-L/home/saga//.local/lib -pthread -lre2`

Comment: Okay. Did you try telling that to `g++`?

Comment: Tried the solution offered below, getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually *using* `pkg-config`...

```
$ g++ $(pkg-config --cflags re2) tst.cpp
```

Comment: Just tried it, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: "There's an `re2` directory in `/home/saga//.local/include` which contains `re2.h`."

Comment: @saga I first misread the question. Sorted now.

Comment: Still getting the same error. The output of `pkg-config --cflags re2` is `-std=c++11 -pthreads`

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `-I/` there as well.

Comment: @saga Yes, there should be. But I see nothing wrong with the `.pc` file.

Comment: @saga `-pthreads`, really?  The `.pc` file says `-pthread` (no `s` at the end).

Comment: Yes, there's no `s`. Should've copy pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running pkg-config in debug mode with:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags-only-I re2 --debug
```

It should print something like this:

```
< cut >
Looking for package 're2'
Looking for package 're2-uninstalled'
Reading 're2' from file '/home/saga/.local/lib/pkgconfig/re2.pc'
Parsing package file '/home/saga/.local/lib/pkgconfig/re2.pc'
  line>prefix=/home/saga//.local
 Variable declaration, 'prefix' has value '/home/saga//local'
  line>exec_prefix=/home/saga//.local
 Variable declaration, 'exec_prefix' has value '/home/saga//local'
  line>includedir=/home/saga//.local/include
 Variable declaration, 'includedir' has value '/home/saga//.local/include'
  line>libdir=/home/saga//.local/lib
 Variable declaration, 'libdir' has value '/home/saga//.local/lib'
  line>
  line>Name: re2
  line>Description: RE2 is a fast, safe, thread-friendly regular expression engine.
  line>Version: 0.0.0
  line>Cflags: -std=c++11 -pthread -I${includedir}
  line>Libs: -pthread -L${libdir} -lre2
Path position of 're2' is 1
Adding 're2' to list of known packages
  pre-remove: re2
 post-remove: re2
 original: re2
   sorted: re2
adding CFLAGS_I string "-I/home/saga//.local/include "
returning flags string "-I/home/saga//.local/include "
-I/home/saga//.local/include
```

You can see that the last line is what you're currently missing.